# silverlight 2 binding data to transforms?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, silverlight-2.0

I am working on creating a tag cloud in Silverlight 2 and trying to bind data from a List collection to a Scale transform on a TextBlock.  When running this I get an `AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE` error. Is it possible to data bind values to transforms in Silverlight 2? If not could I do something to the effect of FontSize={Binding Weight*18} to multiply the tag's weight by a base font size?  I know this won't work, but what is the best way to calculate property values for items in a DataTemplate?

```
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:IsStaticText="False" Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Foreground="#FF1151A8" FontSize="18" UseLayoutRounding="False" Margin="4,4,4,4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
<TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=WeightPlusOne}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=WeightPlusOne}"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</TextBlock.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: This is one of the things I'm looking forward to in Silverlight 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be [Rule #1 from this post](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/data-and-silverlight-2-data-binding/):

> The target of data binding must be a FrameworkElement.

So since ScaleTransform isn't a FrameworkElement it doesn't support binding. I tried to bind to a SolidColorBrush to test this out and got the same error as with the ScaleTransform.

So in order to get around this you can create a control that exposes a dependency property of your tag data type. Then have a property changed event that binds the properties of your tag data to the properties in the control (one of which would be the scale transform). Here is the code I used to test this out.

items control:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <local:TagControl TagData="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

tag control xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightTesting.TagControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    >
    <TextBlock x:Name="text" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" Margin="4,4,4,4">
      <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTx" />
      </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

tag control code:

```
public partial class TagControl : UserControl
{
    public TagControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Tag TagData
    {
        get { return (Tag)GetValue(TagDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TagDataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TagData.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TagDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TagData", typeof(Tag), typeof(TagControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TagControl.OnTagDataPropertyChanged)));

    public static void OnTagDataPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tc = obj as TagControl;
        if (tc != null) tc.UpdateTagData();
    }

    public void UpdateTagData()
    {
        text.Text = TagData.Title;
        scaleTx.ScaleX = scaleTx.ScaleY = TagData.Weight;
        this.InvalidateMeasure();
    }

}
```

Seems like overkill for just setting a single property, but I couldn't find an easier way.